# Where do I put a piece of code that I want to run right before a multi-form Windows form app exits? (no matter how the program exits)

Tags: c#, exit

I have a C# application that consists of multiple forms, and there is no particular one which will always be closed last.

Where should I put a piece of code (i.e. dumping some information to a file) to ensure that no matter how the program exits, this happens just before the program closes?

Comment: The app domain process exit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033100/unload-event-for-the-default-application-domain

Comment: The only scenarios you'll be able to account for are any "natural" closing of the program. Closing the program in Task Manager, or a power fault to the computer (pushing the power button or losing power) are two scenarios you can't do anything about. Task Manager could be a real concern, especially if your "closing code" is something that takes a really long time.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2555354)

Comment: WinForms, and I suppose I could do without it for stuff like killing the process in task manager, but definitely would like it for every natural closing of the program. Is there a particular place to put this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one option would be to call a method to do what ever you want right before the main method exits.

ETA:

by default the main method is in the program.cs file.

here is an example of what I mean

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        //** this code will not be reached until form1 closes.
        bool blah = true;
        doWhatEver(blah);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the main method in a winforms application?